# Can 2-by-2 elementary matrices be written as commutator of elementary matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

I am doing project in which we are proving that for a Euclidean domain $A$ subgroup $E_n(A)$, generated by elementary matrix of third type(For definition : http://web.mnstate.edu/jamesju/Spr2012/Content/M327Elem&InvMatrices.pdf, is same as special linear group $SL_n(A)$ on $A$.

To prove it I need to prove $$[E_n(A),E_n(A)] = E_n(A), \forall n\in \mathbb N,$$ where $[E_n(A),E_n(A)]$ is commutator group generated by commutators. I am unable to prove the case $n=2$.

Thanks to https://math.stackexchange.com/users/386889/anne-bauval by @anne-bauval.

So, we only need to show that $E_2(A)\subseteq [E_2(A),E_2(A)]$. To be very specific we want to show that $e_{12}(1) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 0 &1\end{bmatrix}$ can be written as a product of commutators of elementary matrix of third type only.

I have checked that $e_{12}(1) $ can not be written as $aba^{-1}
b^{-1}$ for $a,b$ elementary matrix of third type.

Any hint is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: It would help if you included in your post the outcome of your calculation of the commutator of $e_{12}(\lambda)$ and $e_{21}(\lambda)$, together with some account of what happened when you tried to reduce it to the identity matrix.

Comment: @LeeMosher Now i am not able to proceed from here.

Comment: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Every_elementary_matrix_of_the_first_kind_is_a_commutator_of_invertible_matrices I think your title should rater be: "Are elementary matrices generated by commutators thereof?" (because obviously, we already have $[E_n(A),E_n(A)]\subseteq E_n(A)$). + I don't understand why you want to "prove that the matrix can be reduced to identity matrix by row and column operation of third kind".

Comment: So by inspecting the outcome of your calculation, it is clear that matrix is not an elementary matrix, which addresses the actual question in your title. Also, reading the statement of your project in your first sentence, I do not see what that project has to do with commutators. So I'm somewhat at a loss what you are really asking.

Comment: @AnneBauval How you are claiming that $[E_n(A),E_n(A)]\subseteq E_n(A)$? I need proof for $n=2$ case only. I had seen the link which you have provided but there also they haven't discussed $n=2$ case

Comment: You defined $E_n(A)$ as the *subgroup generated by* elementary matrices. For any group $G,$ $[G,G]\subseteq G.$ So your only problem is the converse (and again: your title should be corrected). The link also proves the $n=2$ case when $A$ is a field with more than $2$ elements. I know it does not fully adress your question since you are interested in Euclidean domains, but it should help.

Comment: About your today's (2023-01-25) question, you shouldn't have deleted it, because it is interesting. The fact that a question is marked as a "duplicate" shouldn't induce that it has to be suppressed.

Comment: @JeanMarie Now I have put that question here itself now if you can comment something on it please do comment. I am still looking for its solution.

Comment: 1) Paraphrasing a famous film title : I have never encountered an "elementary matrix of the third kind". Could you say what it is ? 2) Your notation with brackets should be kept for the other concept of "commutator" $[A,B]=AB-BA$.

Comment: @JeanMarie I have not cleared your both the two points. Now do you see any hint to this problem?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something, but your statement doesn't seem to hold if $A$ is a field with $2$ or $3$ elements. Since these are Euclidean domains, you need to know that your domain has elements $0$, $1$, $-1$ and $w$ for some other element $w$.

Comment: Yes@DavidA.Craven you are correct. Today I discussed it with my professor, and he said that it's not true and the concrete example itself is field with two elements. I had misunderstood the point the project now its clear.